# Tangent Space: Identifications

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, definition, partial-derivative

Given a manifold $M$.

Denote a chart by $\kappa$.

Introduce the directional derivative:
$$\partial:\mathbb{R}^n_a\to T_a\mathbb{R}^n:v\mapsto\partial_v\rvert_a$$

That is an isomorphism with inverse being:
$$\varepsilon:T_a\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n_a:\delta_a\mapsto\oplus_{k=1}^n\delta_a(\pi_k)$$

Is there a short and elegant way to express these maps?

I'm thinking of something like e.g. differentials:
$$(D\kappa)_p:T_pU\to T_\hat{p}\hat{U}$$
$$(D\iota)_p:T_pA\to T_pM$$
$$(D\pi_M)_{(p,q)}:T_{(p,q)}(M\times N)\to T_pM$$

Comment: Your question is a little bit vague. Could you clarify what you mean by elegant?

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow: Elegant in the sense that it can be described in words as the differential the gradient the evaluation or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As there was nothing better coming up let me close this tread by noting...*

The first map is nothing but the directional derivative.

The second map is at most an evaluation of projections.